# How to Merge Working Branch A into New Branch B Locally..?

Tags: git, git-bash, merge-conflict-resolution, git-gui

I have Branch A(Where I am coding),I have Identified the branch that I created(branch A)from GitBash was not appearing on GitHub Repo.
Steps Done:

```
git clone url@git.com
git checkout -b branchA
```

Now Want to take master piece into another branch from git.

```
git clone url@git.com
git checkout branchB ( I have created on Github)
```

Now Wanna Merge Branch A into Branch B and make Branch B Active...?
Share me some best commands or How to merger locally with out loosing my code and getting conflicts..

Thank you Folks.
JB

Comment: Why would you need to git clone _twice_?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to identify the difference using `git diff FIRST-BRANCH..SECOND-BRANCH`

I think this will work for your situation

```
git chechout branchA
git add .
git commit -m "msg"
git pull
git push origin branchB
git checkout branchB
```

I suggest you to make a backup of your repository to be secure

Answer (score 0):

**If your branch is not showing in your hub probably you have not pushed it yet**

```
git checkout branch -B
git add . 
git commit -m "message"
git push origin branch -B
```

**if you want to merge two branches**

```
git checkout "Branch in which you want to add"
git merge "Branch which you want to add"
git push origin "branch name"
```

**now you will see all the commits in that branch on the Github**